# Popup Windows Gravity work different in Emulator and Real device

Tags: android, popupwindow

Popup show in Emulator:

[image: Popup Show in Emulator]

Popup show in Real device:

[image: Popup show in real device]

As you can see, the popup shown in Emulator more correct than in real device. I don't know why.
It's happened when i modify the popup to get focus for EditText:

```
container = inflater.inflate(R.layout.play_exercise_popup, null);
fadeContainer = inflater.inflate(com.phongphonix.trackingbodybuilding.R.layout.faded_popup, null);
popupWindow = new PopupWindow(container, CommonLib.convertDpToPx(activity, 350), LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
fadePopup = new PopupWindow(fadeContainer, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, false);
fadePopup.showAtLocation(viewHolder.containerTest, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 0, 0);
popupWindow.showAtLocation(viewHolder.containerTest, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
popupWindow.setTouchInterceptor(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE) {
                                popupWindow.dismiss();
                                return true;
                            }
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
popupWindow.setOnDismissListener(new PopupWindow.OnDismissListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDismiss() {
                            fadePopup.dismiss();
                        }
                    });

 popupWindow.update();
```

What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: use Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL rather than Gravity.CENTER